# Why is Option<&T> is not consumed by .copied()?

Tags: rust

I wrote a function to learn about `Option` in Rust:

```
fn f1() {
    let a: Option<i32> = Some(1);
    let b: Option<&i32> = a.as_ref();
    let c: Option<i32> = b.copied();  // I thought b is moved.
    println!("{:?}", b);              // use a reference of b, why no errors?
}
```

I found the signature of `copied` is like this so the `Option<&T>` should be consumed:

```
impl<T> Option<&T> {
    pub fn copied(self) -> Option<T>
    where
        T: Copy
    ...
```

I guess it's because of a blanket implementation:

```
impl<T> Copy for Option<T>
where
    T: Copy,
```

I know `i32` implements `Copy` (in the [std document](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/primitive.i32.html#impl-Copy-for-i32)), but I didn't find anything about `&i32` implementing `Copy`. Could someone help me?

Comment: From [`std::marker::Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html), it reads "Shared references (`&T`) are also Copy, so [...]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`&T` also implements `Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#impl-Copy-for-%26T), which means that a shared reference to any type can be copied. The blanket impl looks like this:

```rust
impl<T> Copy for &T
where
    T: ?Sized,
```

Mutable references, on the other hand, cannot be copied.